# JSON value replace with lookup from another file

Tags: python, bash, shell, awk

I have a json as:

"key1" : "value1"

"key2" : "value2"

and another file as:

value1 valueA

value2 valueB

I need to replace json values(value1, value2) to values from the file (valueA, valueB). Do we have any python or shell script to recursively read the values from file lookup in son and replace it with second column values!

Comment: No, we don't have any. Sorry.

Comment: The `json` module is your friend.

Comment: Python, or bash? You could use either -- but pick one, or the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest [***jq***](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/) (advanced JSON manipulation tool)

Input files:

*test.json*:

```
{
"key1" : "value1",
"key2" : "value2"
}
```

*values.txt*:

```
value1 valueA
value2 valueB
```

***jq*** solution:

```
jq -s '.[0] as $v | [ .[1] | to_entries | .[] 
       | if $v[(.value)]!=null then .value |= $v[.] else . end] 
       | from_entries' \
       <(jq -Rs '[split("\n") | .[] | split(" ") | select(length>0)] 
                 | reduce .[] as $a({}; .[$a[0]] |= $a[1])' values.txt) test.json
```

The output:

```
{
  "key1": "valueA",
  "key2": "valueB"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try to write such a script. You would need to

- read in the replacement data, and organize it into a convenient data structure, like a `dict()`.
- read in and parse the original json.
- iterate over the data from the original json, modifying as necessary
- write the data to a new json file.

Here is such a script:

```
import json

with open('another.txt') as another:
    replacements = dict(line.split() for line in another)

with open('ajson.json') as j:
    data = json.load(j)

data = {k: replacements.get(v, v) for k,v in data.items()}

with open('ajson_new.json', 'w') as j:
    json.dump(data, j)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do the job, providing the data is seperated in a file with a space separating the columns.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

dict_ = {
    "key1" : "value1",
    "key2" : "value2",
    }

def fileToDictionary(FILENAME):
    lines = [line.rstrip() for line in open(FILENAME)]
    return {k:v for (k, v) in [x.split(' ') for x in lines]}

fileDictionary = fileToDictionary(FILENAME)

items = {k: fileDictionary[v] for (k, v) in dict_.items()}

print(items)
# {'key1': 'valueA', 'key2': 'valueB'}
```